# What if a log transformation wipes out significance in regression?

Tags: statistical-significance, data-transformation, least-squares, outliers

I'm doing an OLS regression of donations made by individuals to a not-for-profit organisation. The donation amount is the dependent variable and dummy (treatment) variables are the only independent variables.

The non-transformed treatment variable is significant (5% level), but when I take a log of the donation amount (not treatment), the treatment variables become highly insignificant.

Does this show an outlier problem and should not be used for interpretation of the data?

Comment: what do you mean by "dummy (treatment)" variables?

Comment: If you are worried about outliers or influential points in your original or transformed model, it is worthwhile to perform a proper set of regression diagnostics. If you are doing your analysis in R you may find http://www.gmw.rug.nl/~boomsma/apstatdata/Regrdiag_R.pdf helpful, although it doesn't cover all diagnostic approaches. What is the reason you chose to perform a log transformation - was there a known theoretical result, or a pattern in your data, that made you suspect this is the correct functional form?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are running a t-test, w/ donation amount as the DV, & treatment as the IV. Is that right? Now, for some reason, you feel compelled to log transform your DV, but if you do so, the t-test is no longer significant. Is that right? If so, why do you believe you should transform your DV?

Comment: What do the conditional distributions look like?

Answer (score 5):

The proper solution depends on the nature of your dependent variable: donation amount.

If this takes on a small number of integer values (in number of dollars or Euros  or whatever) and those integers are all small (or adjacent) then some sort of count model is appropriate (as @Tomas notes). This could be Poisson or negative binomial regression, or perhaps a zero-inflated version of these, if you are interested in who gave nothing.

If donation amount takes on a small number of levels, but those values are widely dispersed (as might be if people were responding to a request that had a number of donation levels and check boxes) then an ordinal logistic regression might be correct.

However, if donation amount takes on a large number of levels and they are widely dispersed and there are no zeroes (e.g. some people give \$10, some give $10,000, most give somewhere in between) then it might be that a log transformation is correct or it might be that you need some form of robust regression. It depends partly on substantive questions: Are differences in amount given better looked at on arithmetic or multiplicative scale?  That is, which of these two differences are equivalent?

1) The difference between \$10 and \$20 is the same as the difference between \$1000 and $1010?

2) The difference between \$10 and \$20 is the same as the difference between \$1000 and $2000?

If 1) then some robust regression is probably better; if 2) then a log transform.

One thing that seems very unlikely to me is that the regular (OLS) regression on the untransformed donation amount could be correct. But you'd have to examine residual plots to be sure.

Comment: A difficulty expressing whether arithmetic/multiplicative scales are preferable, is that the very word "difference" strongly suggests subtraction and the arithmetic scale (if read too literally, the difference between 10 and 20, or 1000 and 1010, _is_ 10). I suppose another way to express the distinction, is that if a "_proportional_ difference" is more appropriate then a multiplicative scale is preferred. Let's say sex is one of the binary IVs: is (1) "on average women give 18 dollars more than men" more appropriate than (2) "on average women give 23% more than men"?

Answer (score 2):

Amount (donation) is a count so first thing that comes to my mind is a Poisson regression. This actually uses the log link function. The fact that the relationship is no longer significant does not necessarily mean that the model is less accurate. This is also related to [the difference between accuracy and precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision).

I cannot say more until I know more about your dependent variable.

Comment: Even if donations are not thought of as counts, their values are positive and likely to be skewed, so something like a Poisson is still likely to be appropriate (more generally, a generalized linear model with log link). Presumably you have no zeros in your data, but if you did, the same point applies.